# Create data generator with tf.data.dataset for sequence models

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets, data-generation, tf.data.dataset

I have an image dataset including RGB images: img1.png, img2.png ... img250.png. I have extracted 100 small patches with size [64,64,3] from each image. So, I have now dataset like img1_1.png, img1_2.png ...img1_100.png, img2_1.png, img2_2.png, ... img2_100.png, img3_1, .....

I want to create a data generator with tf.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices to pass all patches of each image to an RNN model. So, I wanna the generator creates output like this : [batch_size, 100, 64, 64, 3]

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean in format (batch_size, 64, 64, 3)? If not what does the batch_size indicate?

Comment: No, I need the format (batch_size, sequence_len, 64, 64, 3). The batch_size is the number of batches that pass through the sequence model ( for example batch_size = 20). the sequence_len is also the number of sequence patches that pass through the RNN model in each iteration, the sequence_len in my model is 100.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
# generating data
x = tf.constant(np.random.randint(256, size =(250,64, 64, 3)), dtype = tf.int32)

# Creating a dataset with sequence length
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(100, drop_remainder= True)
for i in dataset:
    print(i.shape)
```

Output:

```
(100, 64, 64, 3)
(100, 64, 64, 3)
```

Make sure the `drop_remainders = True`

Finally, create a batch size of the desired length.

```
# creating dataset with batch_size
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
for i in dataset:
    print(i.shape)
```

Output:

```
(2, 100, 64, 64, 3)
```

If your data size is (250,100,64, 64, 3):

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).batch(32)
for i in dataset:
    print(i.shape)
```

Output:

```
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(32, 100, 64, 64, 3)
(26, 100, 64, 64, 3)
```