# Dataset generated from image_dataset_from_directory function does not include batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

According to Keras documentation image_dataset_from_directory() returns:

```
A tf.data.Dataset object. 
- If label_mode is None, it yields float32 tensors of shape (batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels), encoding images (see below for rules regarding num_channels). 
- Otherwise, it yields a tuple (images, labels), where images has shape (batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels), and labels follows the format described below.

Rules regarding labels format: 
- if label_mode is int, the labels are an int32 tensor of shape (batch_size,).
- if label_mode is binary, the labels are a float32 tensor of 1s and 0s of shape (batch_size, 1). 
- if label_mode is categorial, the labels are a float32 tensor of shape (batch_size, num_classes), representing a one-hot encoding of the class index
```

Whereas when I use it :

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    class_names=["0", "10", "5"],
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

I get (None, 224,224,3) for the images and (None,3) for the labels even though I set label_mode to "categorical". The batch size is not added into the shape even when I explicitly set the batch_size to 32(defaults to 32 but I tried it to see if it makes a difference). I have been having issues training my model because of this as the batch size needs to be included for a TimeDistributed layer.

```
#train_dataset.element_spec
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

Edit:
I'm trying to figure out why I get the following error when training a model using transfer learning from MobileNetV2 with LSTM for video classification and figured the batch_size not being present in the dataset was the issue.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 224, 224, 3]
```

Code for the models:

MobilenetV2 function:

```
def build_mobilenet(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, nbout=CLASSES):

    # INPUT_SHAPE = (224,224,3)

    # CLASSES = 3

    model = MobileNetV2(

        include_top=False,

        input_shape=shape,

        weights='imagenet')

    base_model.trainable = True

    output = GlobalMaxPool2D()

    return Sequential([model, output])
```

LSTM function:

```
def action_model(shape=INSHAPE, nbout=3):

    # INSHAPE = (5, 224, 224, 3)

    convnet = build_mobilenet(shape[1:])
    
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(TimeDistributed(convnet, input_shape=shape))

    model.add(LSTM(64))

    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dropout(.5))

    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dropout(.5))

    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dropout(.5))

    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(nbout, activation='softmax'))

    return model
```

Comment: Can you add the issues or errors that you are getting? Because TensorFlow adds batch size in run time and I don't see any issue with the shape of categorical labels. Since you have 3 categories you will get the shape of (None, 3).

Comment: Sure please check the edit

Comment: What does 5 in INSHAPE of action_model represent?

Comment: It represents the number of frames I'm passing it at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not an issue with batch size. But your input data format.
Code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

def build_mobilenet(shape=(224,224,3), nbout=3):
    model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=shape,
        weights='imagenet')
    model.trainable = True
    output = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D()
    return tf.keras.Sequential([model, output])


def action_model(shape=(5, 224, 224, 3), nbout=3):
    convnet = build_mobilenet()
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(convnet, input_shape=shape))
    model.add(LSTM(64))
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(nbout, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = action_model()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'my_first_model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

This gives output:

[image]

As you can see the model expects a 5d tensor as input but what you are providing is 4d tensor.

This model works with 5d tensor:

Code:

```
x = tf.constant(np.random.randint(50, size =(32,5,224,224,3)), dtype = tf.float32)
model(x)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.30153075, 0.3630225 , 0.33544672],
       [0.3018494 , 0.36799458, 0.33015603],
       [0.2965148 , 0.36714798, 0.3363372 ],
       [0.30032247, 0.36478844, 0.33488905],
       [0.30106384, 0.36145815, 0.33747798],
       [0.29292756, 0.3652076 , 0.34186485],
       [0.29766476, 0.35945407, 0.34288123],
       [0.29290855, 0.36984667, 0.33724475],
       [0.30804047, 0.35799438, 0.33396518],
       [0.30497718, 0.35853127, 0.33649153],
       [0.29357925, 0.36751047, 0.33891028],
       [0.29514724, 0.36558747, 0.33926526],
       [0.29731706, 0.3684161 , 0.33426687],
       [0.30811843, 0.3656716 , 0.32621   ],
       [0.29937437, 0.36403805, 0.33658758],
       [0.2967953 , 0.36977535, 0.3334294 ],
       [0.30307695, 0.36372742, 0.33319563],
       [0.30148408, 0.36562964, 0.33288625],
       [0.29590267, 0.36651734, 0.33758003],
       [0.29640752, 0.36192682, 0.3416656 ],
       [0.30003947, 0.36704347, 0.332917  ],
       [0.29541495, 0.3681183 , 0.33646676],
       [0.29900452, 0.36397702, 0.33701843],
       [0.3028345 , 0.36404026, 0.33312523],
       [0.30092967, 0.36406764, 0.33500263],
       [0.29969287, 0.36108258, 0.33922455],
       [0.29743004, 0.36917207, 0.3333979 ],
       [0.29056188, 0.3742272 , 0.33521092],
       [0.30297956, 0.36698693, 0.3300335 ],
       [0.29843566, 0.3594078 , 0.3421565 ],
       [0.29280537, 0.36777246, 0.33942217],
       [0.29983717, 0.3691762 , 0.33098662]], dtype=float32)>
```

The image_dataset_from_directory function you are using is not capable of generating 5d tensors. You have to use a custom data generator to generate 5d tensors from your data.

Comment: Thanks that explains it. But I've no idea how to make a custom one. Do you know any of them?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the dataset. As you said you need 5 frames in 1 example ie (1,5,224,224,3) represents your single example. Now if you 100 examples in your training data ie(100,224,224,3). You can reshape it using the reshape method. ie `x.reshape((20,5,224,224,3))`. And if you have a dataset object. You can use the batch method twice to get the desired shape. ie `train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(5).batch(32)`.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655098/create-data-generator-with-tf-data-dataset-for-sequence-models/63655521#63655521).

Comment: You can also take a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#preprocessing_data)

Comment: If you add batch value to train_dataset your labels will also get batched. You have to create a new dataset object based on how your data is formatted. Essentially you are combining 5 images in 1 example which means you have 1 label for those 5 images but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll recommend you to ask another question which provides information about your data and required data format.

Comment: I have 529003 frames in the train dataset so how would I do it for a dataset of this size. I tried it and got the same error :
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_34 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6. Full shape received: [None, None, None, 224, 224, 3]

Comment: I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706030/how-do-i-convert-train-dataset-frames-into-5d-tensor-while-maintaining-label-of