# How do I convert train dataset frames into 5d tensor while maintaining label of frames dimension?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have used the image_dataset_from_directory() to create my train(529003 frames), validation(29388 frames) and test(28875 frames) data:

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_DIR,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    class_names=["0", "10", "5"],
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)

#Shape of the data
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

The model I am using expects the data in the form of a 5D tensor (32,5,224,224,3)
I am using transfer learning with MobileNet then a LSTM for video classification.

I have tried using :

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(5).batch(32)
```

But the dataset becomes 6D and the labels increase in dimension as well

```
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I need to make a custom generator that generates 5D Tensors from video input which considers the sequence length as the 5th element of the 5D Tensor. The one I am using from Keras, image_dataset_from_directory() produces a 4D Tensor.